# How to render multiple forms in a single page using Material Design for django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

How can we display two forms in a single page using the Material Design for django forms?

In the forms.py, we can add code like

```
template = Template("""
    {% form %}
        {% part form.username prefix %}<i class="material-icons prefix">account_box</i>{% endpart %}
        {% part form.email prefix %}<i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>{% endpart %}
        {% part form.password prefix %}<i class="material-icons prefix">lock_open</i>{% endpart %}
    {% endform %}
    """)
```

And then in the template we have

```
{% block formbody %}
    {% include form.template %}
{% endblock %}
```

How we can add one more form to the page say form2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in [the documentation](http://docs.viewflow.io/forms_templatetags.html):

> Options:
>
> form - form instance to render, if not specified, takes from **form** context variable

(emphasis mine)

So to render a different form:

```
{% form form=login_modal %}
     form code here
{% endform %}
```

This means that in your view, you need to provide the context variable bound to the form:

```
from viewflow.flow.views import PerformTaskView
from .forms import LoginForm

class MyView(PerformTaskView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['login_modal'] = LoginForm()
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  Worked well